# Is there a proper way to convert a Double to a Float in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a double being retrieved from an iPhone sensor into a float. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any resources on built in functionality to do so.

If I initialize a Float or a cast to a Float from a double like so:

```
let roll  = (Float)(attitude!.roll)
let pitch  = (Float)(attitude!.pitch)
```

Or

```
let roll = Float(attitude!.roll)
let pitch = Float(attitude!.pitch)
```

the original Double values still don't get converted properly.
For instance, `9.436222` and `27.895268` become `0.486864` and `0.164693` respectively. Is there a proper way to cast to a Float from a Double that preserves the larger decimal value?

Comment: your second code snippet seems perfectly fine - something else has to be wrong with your code!

Comment: I can run a simple playground converting doubles to floats with those exact numbers you listed and I get the correct values. There is precision loss, but I am not seeing the incorrect values you are getting.

Comment: Yep! Turns out that when you call `.attitude` on the motion manager, it'll display the Roll, Pitch, and Yaw, in degrees, but when you call `.roll`, or `.pitch`, or `.yaw` in degrees on `.attitude`, it gives those individual components in radians!

Comment: @zavtra If you question has been answered, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
guard let unwrappedAttitude = attitude else { 
    fatalError("attitude was nil!")
}

let roll = Float(unwrappedAttitude.roll)
let pitch = Float(unwrappedAttitude.pitch)
```

should be the way to go.